# Clarifications of problem with parameters: the relationship between matrices and endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $R^3$ such that $f(a,b,c)=(2b,a-b,b)$. I don't understand how I can see for which values of $k\in R$ there esist $$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & k & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & k+1\end{pmatrix}$$is the matrix associated to f with respect to some basis B.

Also, if $W=<(3,-1,0),(3,1,0)>$ and $g:W \to R^3$ the restriction of $f$ to $W$ and the basis $B' = (0,1,-1),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ of $R^3$ how can I see if $$\begin{pmatrix}- 1/2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 1/2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ is the matrix associated with $g$ for some basis $B_0$?

Comment: Is $g$ the map induced by $f$/the restriction of $f$ to $W$? If not, what is it?

Comment: @quid Yes, it is the restriction.

Comment: Sorry it is still not completely clear to me now, is $B_0 $ some basis of $W$?

Comment: @quid Yes. I have to find if there exist a basis $B_0$ such that that matrix is associated to $g$ with respect to $B_0$.

Comment: Thanks it is clear now. But I cannot think of a slick way to do this :( [Only a lengthy calculation.]

Comment: @quid Could you show me that lenghty procedure, please (even if you don't do every single calculation)?

Comment: @quid As a side question: I know that if $A$ and $B$ are matrices associated with the same endomorphism with respect to different basis, then $A$ and $B$ are similar. Can you tell me what is the matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$? Similarly, if $A$ and $B$ represent the same bilinear form with respect to different bases, then $A$ and $B$ are congruent. Can you tell me what is the matrix $P$ such that $B=P^tAP$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure. If $B$ is with respect to some basis $F$ and $A$ with respect to some basis $E$ then the $P$ such that $B = P^{-1}A P $ is the matrix associated with the identity map with respect to basis $F$ for the domain and $E$ for the image. More concretely, if $E$ is the canonical basis than $P$ contains as columns the elements of $F$. Same for bilinear form.

Comment: For your other question for the second part. I do not even have a good idea how to sketch that. I think I am missing something. Sorry. If something comes to mind I will let you know. (But do not wait for it; I will be gone for at least a couple of hours, likely more.)

Comment: @quid I don't understand clearly what you said about the matrices: "matrix associated with the identity map with respect to basis F for the domain and E for the image" isn't the contrary of "if E is the canonical basis than P contains as columns the elements of F". Could I ask you to add to your answer a couple of examples (for the case of the endomorphism and for the case of the bilinear form), please? It would really help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added the transformation matrix. Sorry, I still do not see how to do the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the first part of your problem, note that if the diagonal matrix is a matrix associated to $f$ then the eigenvalues of $f$ are $-2, k, k+1$ and the endomorphism is diagonalizable.

So let us check if this is the case. With respect to the canonical basis we get the matrix for $f$:

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The characteristic polynomial is $-x(-1 - x)(-x) + 2x = -x^3 - x^2 + 2x = -x (x^2 + x - 2)= -x (x-1)(x+ 2)$.

Thus you have the eigenvalues $0,1, -2$. Thus with $k=0$ the matrix is a matrix associated to $f$, a basis can be found by taking  eigenvectors  associated to $-2$, $0$, $1$, resp., in that order.

If you want an actual matrix that transforms the matrix above into a diagonal one, compute the eigenvectors and put the eigenvectors into a basis as columns. One has  eigenvectors $(1,-1,1/2)$ , $(0,0,1)$ and $(2,1,1)$, for $-2, 0, 1$, resp.

So we get a matrix
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
1/2 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
then $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal. Note that $P$ is the matrix that represents the identity map, when in the domain you used the basis of eigenvectors and in the image use the canonical basis; this is because then in the domain $(1,0,0)$ will represent the first eigenvector, and multiplied by $P$ this is the first eigenvector in the canonical basis.